# Using DISTINCT, COUNT and HAVING in a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I want to count all players that have a sum of at least 300 points after a given date. I have this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT playerID)
FROM
    table
WHERE
    game_date > '$date'
HAVING
    SUM(points) >= 300
```

Which is counting also the players that have a sum of less than 300 points. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Andre Bossard:

To get the list of all players with points>=300:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT playerID, SUM(points) points FROM table WHERE game_date>'$date' GROUP BY playerID) a WHERE points>=300
```

To get the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT playerID, SUM(points) points FROM table WHERE game_date>'$date' GROUP BY playerID) a WHERE points>=300
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery for that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
(
  SELECT playerID, SUM(points) AS `total`
  FROM `table`
  WHERE game_date > '$date'
  GROUP BY playerID
) tmp
WHERE total>=300
```

Comment: Oh, never mind. It was a typo on my end. It works, but rationalboss got the right answer first. Thanks.

Comment: @rlcabral there was a typo, I fixed it.